# Defaulting to index.html when no path specified in the URL

Tags: scala, playframework, routes

I am using Play Framework 2.8.

I set routes to:

```
GET  /*file     controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
```

Or:

```
GET  /    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
```

None of them seem to default to `index.html` if no path is specified.

Is there a setting in routes to default `xxx.test.com` to `xxx.test.com/index.html`?

Comment: What do you obtain when you go to `/` with these routes?

Comment: just redirect to whatever url you want on route match fail ?

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. I had these in the wrong order
GET /        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file="index.html")
GET  /*file        controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)

Had the */file as the first changing them around like I did fixed the issue.

Thank you all.